# Image copy with batch

Tags: command-line, batch, photos

i want to copy the images located in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Pictures in a specific folder with batch, I try with this code but it don't work:

```
xcopy /s/e "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Pictures\" ".\"%USERNAME%\Photo"
```

Someone help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, I would like to suggest edit the post and write the Error message will help readers to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra quotation mark in command right before %USERNAME% in destination path.

Comment: Yes, and the ".\%username%\photo" part implies that the current directory must be "C:\users" or it will also fail..